# Why is ASP.NET Identity 2.0 dbo.AspNetUsers Id a string instead of an int?

Tags: string, integer, asp.net-identity, identity

ASP.NET Identity 2.0 dbo.AspNetUsers defined as a string:

```
Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128)
```

When it could be defined as integer:

```
Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true)
```

Why is that so? What are the +/- of this?

Does it makes sense to change it to integer or there's a risk of screwing everything?

Comment: [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) you can find how to change it and [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=integer%20vs%20string%20primary%20key) about +/- of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is ASP.NET Identity 2.0 using a GUID/string as user id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891446/why-is-asp-net-identity-2-0-using-a-guid-string-as-user-id)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already linked answer - Identity is built so it can accommodate any kind of storage. I've seen Azure Tables and plain text files storage implemented. And not all of these can use int/Guid as a primary key, or even have a primary key at all.

So the lowest common denominator for any system - a string. But it can be changed to an int or Guid or whatever your storage supports.

Answer (score -1):

Don't change it. If you notice, the `UserManager` class works only where the primary key is of type string.

Comment: That is not true. You can totally change the type of primary key in Identity