# Why does ASP.Net Core Identity using string for its Primary Key properties?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

By default, [ASP.Net Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) uses the type `string` for the primary key fields of its built-in entities. For example, the `IdentityUser` class has the property `Id` as its primary key and its type is `string`. (This is mapped to type `nvarchar(450)` in SQL Server)

If find this peculiar, especially since by default the values of these keys are actually string representations of `Guid`s:

```
    public IdentityUser()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
```

**Why have the designers of ASP.Net Core Identity chosen to use type `string` for primary keys over, says, type `Guid`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on your question at this time, but I believe this has the answers to the question you are asking:

[Why asp.net Identity user id is string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029182/why-asp-net-identity-user-id-is-string)

Second answer from above post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029268/11191898

> Depending on which version of ASP.Net authentication you're using, on the database ASP.NET Identity v2 should be storing it as a uniqueidentifier (Guid) in the AspNetUsers table. In more preceding versions it will store the user id as an int in the webpages_Membership table.
>
> I believe it surfaces it as a string so it can be any data type you like under the hood and this can then be cast within your code as required.

Comment: Thank you. The second answer in that question suggests the `string` is chosen for the default because it can represent any other data type (serialized). If you'd like to edit your answer to include this information I'll up vote it. :)