# What is the difference between MVC5 identity and MVC4 simple membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, simplemembership

I am building an MVC 5 application and the build in membership function in a basic MVC 5 project is MVC5 Identity. I am familiar to MVC 4 simple membership, but i want to use the new functions of MVC 5. The identity seems a little lean and you have to extend everything.
Can you tell me which one is better for application that needs to handle multiple logins - 1k+
and open authentication ?

Comment: @dlght: Interestingly it can't be marked as a duplicate as the other question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Ian. There are many articles that match the OP's case, for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636345/asp-net-identity. I just took the first one as i didn't know about the duplicate question requirements ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you tell me which one is better for application that needs to
>   handle multiple logins - 1k+ and open authentication ?

Currently, ASP.Net Identity reaches to [Version 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx) already, so we can assume that **SimpleMembership Provider** is deprecated.

Unfortunately, **Identity** is not backward compatible with **SimpleMembership Provider**.

If you are implementing new Application with MVC 5, you definitely want to use new [Identity 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx).